# Finding all generators of subgroups of order $8$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{32}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Could someone help me with this question? I am a little stuck...

> Find all generators of each subgroup of order $8$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{32}$.

By the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups, there is exactly one subgroup $<32/8>=<4>$ of order $8$. Then $<4>=\left \{ 0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28 \right \}$. However, I am not sure how to find the generators for $<4>$. Are they the numbers $x$ in $<4>$ such that $gcd(x,32)=1$?

Comment: What is the formula for the order of an element in a cyclic group of order $n?$ That will answer your gcd question. Another approach is to determine which elements of $<4>$ have order 8, which you can do by trial and error; not my favorite strategy.

Comment: @ChrisLeary Thank you for replying. The formula is $32/gcd(x,32)$ for $x=0,4,8,...,28$? Then the generators are $4,12,20,28$?!

Comment: You're welcome, and you have the correct generators.

Answer (score 1):

*$Hint$* : Try to find the no. of subgroups of order $8$. Generally in a finite ordered cyclic group, no. of subgroups of order $m$ is $φ(m)$.